# Integrating Selenium with Gitlab CI

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, docker, gitlab-ci

I have created an automated selenium test script which works perfectly fine.
My task now is to set up Gitlab CI and try to automatically run this selenium script when I make a push to git.

Is it possible to make the selenium script automatically execute and inform the user if the script runs successfully or it fails?

Thank you

Comment: I guess you should go with some initial gitlabs CI configuration tutorial. Where you will get clearance over this in  detail. If you face some specific issue during that  then you can do a post for help

Comment: Can you provide me a link to any of these tutorials? I've looked everywhere but I have trouble understanding how to write the gitlab yaml file.

Answer (score 0):

How to automatically run Automation Tests on Gitlab Ci with Selenium and specflow with a .net Project ?

If this is something ,you are looking for then .

Here is the core part which is to setup the gitlab-ci.yml file :

Here is how the sample gitlab-ci.yml should look :

```
image: please give your own docker which can download .net stuff 

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2   
  SOURCE_CODE_DIRECTORY: 'src'
  BINARIES_DIRECTORY: 'bin'
  OBJECTS_DIRECTORY: 'obj'
  NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY: '.nuget'
  
stages:
  - Build
  - Test
  
before_script:
  - 'dotnet restore ${SOURCE_CODE_DIRECTORY}/TestProject.sln --packages ${NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY}'

Build:
  stage: Build
  script:
  - 'dotnet build $SOURCE_CODE_DIRECTORY/TestProject.sln --no-restore'

  except:
    - tags
  artifacts:
   paths:
    - '${SOURCE_CODE_DIRECTORY}/*/${BINARIES_DIRECTORY}'
    - '${SOURCE_CODE_DIRECTORY}/*/${OBJECTS_DIRECTORY}'
    - '${NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY}'
   expire_in: 2 hr

Test:
  stage: Test
  services:
    - selenium/standalone-chrome:latest  
  script:
  - 'export MSBUILDSINGLELOADCONTEXT=1' 
  - 'export selenium_remote_url=http://selenium__standalone-chrome:4444/wd/hub/'
  - 'export PATH=$PATH:${SOURCE_CODE_DIRECTORY}/chromedriver.exe'  
  - 'dotnet test $SOURCE_CODE_DIRECTORY/ExpressTestProject.sln --no-restore'
  artifacts:
   paths:
    - '${SOURCE_CODE_DIRECTORY}/chromedriver.exe'
    - '${SOURCE_CODE_DIRECTORY}/*/${BINARIES_DIRECTORY}'
    - '${SOURCE_CODE_DIRECTORY}/*/${OBJECTS_DIRECTORY}'
    - '${NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY}'
```

Thats it .When you set up your  project with this .git-lab-ci.yml ,90 % of your job is done .
The tests will run automatically in Gitlab ,whenever you commit something in your source tree or Tfs.
Thanks